# FFmpeg for the file conversion using URL

Tags: ffmpeg, azure-media-services

i need to be converted from MP4 to AVI. MP4 video are uploaded in window azure blob storage and storage is accessible publicly. 
my question  when we write the ffmpeg command line. can i give the url of the video which is on blob storage

ffmpeg -i https://abcd.blob.core.windows.net/container/1.mp4  D:\Shared\1.avi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your ffmpeg command is correct.

But FFmpeg works only with *http* urls out of the box. To make it work with *https* urls, you will need to [compile](http://ffmpeg.org/platform.html) it yourself with openssl.